# NoClassDefFoundError for MockitoInvocationHandler class

Tags: java, junit4, mockito, powermock

I am using `mockito-all-1.9.5-rc1.jar` and `powermock-mockito-1.4.12-full.jar`.
When I run this simple unit test for mocking final method in non-final class.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ABC.class)
public class ABCTest {

    @Test
    public void finalCouldBeMock() {
        final ABC abc = PowerMockito.mock(ABC.class);
        PowerMockito.when(abc.myMethod()).thenReturn("toto");
        assertEquals("toto", abc.myMethod());
    }

}
```

When I ran it, I got 
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockito/internal/MockitoInvocationHandler
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mockito.internal.MockitoInvocationHandler`

When I search fo class `MockitoInvocationHandler` in `mockito-all-1.9.5-rc1.jar` and `powermock-mockito-1.4.12-full.jar`.  I couldn't find any.
Need help with this issue!  Thank you

Answer (score 15):

Mockito 1.9.5-rc1 had to be refactored internally to allow third party mock maker. `MockitoInvocationHandler` was part of the Mockito's internals (as the package name suggests) up to Mockito 1.9.0.

Due to these changes, <s>current</s> some older version Powermock releases <s>as of today</s> are not compatible with the latest Mockito release.

Another reason to avoid mocking/stubbing finals or statics ;)

Hope that helps
Cheers,

Comment: Hi Brice  that helped a lot.  Thank you.

Comment: @gontard - there is no "must".  However, if someone accepts answers, they're more likely to get answers to subsequent questions that they ask.

Comment: Update - Johan, who looks after PowerMock has posted the following on PowerMock issue 398 (the one that concerns the incompatibilities with Mockito 1.9.5) - "I've now implemented support for 1.9.5-rc1 in trunk. Please try it out by building from source and report an problems."  So I would like to encourage sura watthana to do exactly as Johan suggests.

Comment: "Another reason to avoid mocking/stubbing finals or statics ;)"
This is why library maintenance is a thing.
Upvote for this